# Postgresql running total

Tags: postgresql

I have a bunch on time entries, they have entre_dates and hours associated with them like so.

```sql
drop table if exists data  cascade;
create table time_table (id int, entry_date date, hours numeric);
insert into time_table
values
(1, to_date('01-01-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 1),
(2, to_date('01-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 2),
(3, to_date('01-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 3),
(4, to_date('01-04-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 4),
(5, to_date('01-05-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 5),
(6, to_date('01-06-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 6);
```

For each time entry, I would like to sum all the hours that occur on and before that entry date to get a running total.

Here's my attempt but I have no idea what I'm doing:

```sql
SELECT t1.entry_date, t1.hours, htd.running_total
FROM time_table t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(t2.hours) AS running_total
    FROM time_table t2
    WHERE t2.entry_date <= t1.entry_date
) AS htd ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

I'm trying to get the following result:

```
Date       | Hours | Running Total
-----------------------------------
01-01-2019 | 1     | 1
01-02-2019 | 2     | 3
01-03-2019 | 3     | 6
01-04-2019 | 4     | 10
01-05-2019 | 5     | 15
01-06-2019 | 6     | 21
```

What's the correct way to do this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```sql
    drop table if exists data  cascade;
    create table time_table (id int, entry_date date, hours numeric);
    insert into time_table
    values
    (1, to_date('01-01-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 1),
    (2, to_date('01-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 2),
    (3, to_date('01-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 3),
    (4, to_date('01-04-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 4),
    (5, to_date('01-05-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 5),
    (6, to_date('01-06-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 6);

    select *,
       sum(hours) over(order by entry_date asc rows between unbounded preceding 
     and current row) as running_total
     from time_table
```

db fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ojsazNcvgfaX66CzdRDRXm/1

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: no problem, more information here regarding the window functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS

Comment: I was going to suggest this too. Windowed functions (using the over command) allows you to accomplish rolling avg, sum count et al.